# Expected queue length of a Poisson process while service time is based on an unknown distribution with known expected value $\beta$

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution, queueing-theory

Suppose we have a service provider with an in-process task queue in which tasks arrive based on a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$. Moreover, the service time of each task is based on an unknown distribution with a known expected value $\beta$. Let $Q(t)$ be the size of the task queue at a specific time $t$. What is the expected number of in-process tasks at a specific time $t$? in other words, what is $E[Q(t)]$ or generally $E[Q]$?

Comment: If I did not misundertand you, you are looking for queues in Compound Poisson Processes.  In the first chapter of Andreas E. Kyprianou
''Fluctuations of L ́evy Processes
with Applications
Introductory Lectures
September 5, 2013'' they study exactly that. I hope this helps.

Comment: Looks like you consider an M/G/1 queueing system. But in this case you have to know the variance for your service times to use the Pollaczek–Khinchine formula. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Oleg Thanks a lot for your response. However, this problem is a little bit different from M/G/1. Actually, in my problem, there is no sort of queue because the processing of the tasks would start immediately after arriving at the system.

Comment: Do you mean there are an infinite number of servers?

Comment: If so you should consider an M/G/∞ queueing system, in this case you can obtain transient and stationery distributions.

Comment: @Oleg Thanks a lot, I think Pollaczek–Khinchine formula can be a good point to start.

Comment: In the case of M/G/∞ can I obtain stationery distribution based on expected value?

Comment: Yeah, check Wikipedia M/G/∞ article, for this case the distribution for the number of tasks must be Poisson too.